# Using a custom domain from name.com with heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain, cname

I want to use a domain I bought from name.com to be the domain name to my heroku appliation.
This is what I did.

I added my custom name to my Heroku app.
I copied the DNS Target that Heroku generated.

I then went to name.com and used a CNAME entry.
In the HOST entry, I tried both '*' and 'www' (without the quotes). By both i mean, two different occasions.
In the TARGET entry, I used the DNS Target that Heroku generated.

Now, when I visit my_domain.com I get that this page does not exist.
When I visit www.my_domain.com, I go to the heroku domain, not MY app, and I get a message from heroku that there is nothing here yet.

I get the same results even if i use '*', or 'www' in the HOST entry (without the quotes).

Comment: It can take a little while for the DNS entries to take effect. Maybe an hour or two. I used the "www" CNAME set to the DNS Target generated by Heroku.

Comment: You mean on the HOST entry? You put 'www'?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And the type is CNAME.

Comment: Thank you! But if some user where to go to your website without typing 'www' before the first dot, would it still work?

Comment: No, mine only works with "www.my-domain.com".

Comment: And if you want to work with both?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, sorry. I was under the impression that it had to be one or the other.

Comment: It's ok. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Cheers. Best of luck. If you get it working both with and without www maybe post an answer with that information.

Comment: I will! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

On heroku, use two domain names for your app. One with 'www' and onw wihtout 'www'.

Then, just make two CNAME entries, back on name.com. The one will be the Domain Name with the 'www' from Heroku, with the appropriate DNS Target. The one will be the other domain name, with its appropriate DNS Target.